Cookies not accessible in backend server
req.cookies.jwt is defined in localhost but undefined in deployment. The cookies are being set in the browser, the only problem is I can't access them.
I tried using react-auth-kit but it still doesn't work!
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, decodedToken) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Wrong cookie");
        res.json({ status: false });
        return;
      } else {
        const currUser = await User.findById(decodedToken.id);
        if (currUser) {
          req.user = currUser;
          next();
        } else {
          res.json({ status: false });
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("no cookie");
    res.json({ status: false });
    return;
  }


Here token is undefined.
Refer my github here: https://github.com/sh66n/react-todo for full code

Please verify if cookies are being sent by the browser by taking a look at your network tab. If they aren't, the problem is not with reading the cookie, it's with setting them

You're right, no cookies are being sent at all. How do I fix this?

Hi, it depends upon your request. Please share the same.

const res = await axios.post(
${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_BASEURL}/login,
data,
{
withCredentials: true,
}

Hi, Will I get the URL to test a signup ?

This does not work getitdone-mu.vercel.app

getitdone-sable.vercel.app this is the url

This is the problem domain: process.env.FRONTEND_URL. We cannot create a cookie on behalf of another domain. We can only create cookies with respect to the origin server. You can leave off domain and the browser will set it automatically with resect to the origin server. Or if you want to set it, set it as this domain: process.env.BACKEND_URL.

ok now the cookies are being set, but still the token is undefined, meaning they aren't being sent

Can you now see the cookie under DeveloperTool/Application/Cookies, if yes, what is the domain value against your cookie jwt.

.getitdone-sable.vercel.app this is the domain value

Did you leave it blank, or set it with your backend URL ? try to set it with your backend URL.

Didn't work, got the app working by completely bypassing using cookies and used Authorization header instead. Thanks for the help, but if you do find out the reason for this peculiar behavior please tell me!

Sure, Give me some time, Shall revert in next week.

Please see below a sample server and an application. The app is making a cross-site request. The cookie created is SameSite='none'. And notably the domain has been left off. This was the scenario in which we had stopped our discussion in last week.
Now you can see here, when the domain is left off, it will be set automatically by the Browser with respect to the origin server.
Since the cookie is sameSite='none', it has been included in all subsequent cross-site requests as well.
Note : Both of these apps have been deployed in Vercel.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['https://78958487-f.vercel.app'],
    methods: ['POST', 'GET'],
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
  })
);

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.cookies);

  if (!req.cookies?.someCookie) {
    res
      .cookie('someCookie', 'GET-Somevalue', {
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'None',
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      })
      .send('new cookie created - accessed by get.');
  } else {
    res.send('same cookie passed - accessed by get');
  }
});

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.cookies);
  if (!req.cookies?.someCookie) {
    res
      .cookie('someCookie', 'POST-Somevalue', {
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'None',
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      })
      .send('new cookie created - accessed by post');
  } else {
    res.send('same cookie passed - accessed by post');
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('L@3000');
});

frontend.js
// this app serves the static file index.html kept in the public folder
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('L@3000');
});

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    CORS test 1
  </head>
  <body>
    <p></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    async function fetchdata() {
      const p = document.querySelector('p');
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://78958487-b.vercel.app/', {
          mode: 'cors',
          credentials: 'include',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({ somekey: 1 }),
        });
        p.textContent = await response.text();
      } catch (err) {
        p.textContent = err;
      }
    }
    fetchdata();
  </script>
</html>

Test run 1
Request URL : https://78958487-f.vercel.app/ // typed in the Browser

Output:

Test run 2
Request URL : https://78958487-f.vercel.app/ // typed in the Browser

Output:

Domain set by the Browser


That seems to make sense! Will try to integrate this into the app.

Thank you for your buy-in. Please revert if further help is required.
